# start and stop expressjs app of node.js using php

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, express, npm

I am making a web service. I am using express.js of node.js npm.

To submit this project to my client I need to make a controller file to start and stop the server without using the command prompt in the server.

To start the server, I am using command `set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start` because my server is Linux based.

Is there a way to star and stop my server using PHP to avoid  using the command prompt or terminal in server?

I already referred to this [link](https://github.com/niutech/node.php) but I can't understand how to use it for the express.js framework. Using this file I can only run individual node files. I cannot run `set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start`

Comment: its work for me feel free if error still exist

Comment: check my update answer i solved with set DEBUG=server.js:* & npm start this command also

Comment: accept the answer and vote up pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

- first install express.js properly [How to install express.js from here](http://blog.innovsystems.com/nodejs/getting-started-nodejs-express-framework)
- see if reponse is this then its express install globally and work fine
- type express in CMD if see below response then its mean it install correctly and now u call them out side of directory
  [image: express]
- create your project using express and run here that its working or not then stop it run your php code
- snapshot shows how to make project and run
  [image: here is my express project]
- after running you will see the following screen

[image: express]
 - booom now you are ready start your server from php
 - here node server response 
[image]
 - my php screen output
[image: php response]

now php code will be for express app

```
`exec('set DEBUG=server.js:* & npm start');`

    echo "server run sucessfully";
```

**Note:** do not write app.js write **server.js**

- keep app.js in same directory where your php file is
- make app.js file

`var http = require('http');

    const PORT=9999; 
    function handleRequest(request, response){
        response.end('app.js start from php');
    }
    var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
    server.listen(PORT, function(){
    });`

you php file

```
//for starting
  exec('node server.js');
echo "app.js run sucessfully";}
//for stoping 
    exec('taskkill /f /im node.exe')
        echo "all stoped node.exe instances";
```

> Note you can kill your app.js by PID

Now visit the url you will see the app.js is running

```
http://127.0.0.1:9999/
```

Comment: i don't want to run single file i want to call full application using `set DEBUG=myapp:* & npm start` command. using `node server.js` only single file will be execute. as i told i am use express.js

Comment: so we run over whole application from app.js its like in php index page

Comment: i tired two time so second time i chagned port to 9999